# IOS Keyboard disappear randomly on web input

Tags: ios, reactjs, material-ui, progressive-web-apps

I experience a weird ios keyboard issue on our pwa web page.

As the photo below, the keyboard body disppear while the toolbar remains. And once this situation appear, it will keep like that until I restart the pwa app.

We use react and the input element is a Material-ui Textfield. While there have some conditional render on parent component

```
function handleChange(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  setValue(value);
  return 0
};

<MaterialUi_TextField
      inputProps={"title": "quantity", "onFocus": onFocus, "onBlur": onBlur}
      type={"number"}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />;
```

other info to mention:

- `ios version = 13.4.1, 13.6`
- there is a meta `user-scalable=0` on the page

[image]

Comment: was there a fix to this ? i am facing the same issue , is this because of MUI ?